# Having trouble getting php file uploader to work

Tags: php, upload

I'm having trouble getting a simple php file upload script to work. What happens is I get the Thanks message on my browser, but the file isn't anywhere to be seen.

I've been watching the upload directory and /tmp with inotify to see if anything gets created all but nothing does. Here is the html div that allows selecting the file:

```
<div>
     <p> Select a file </p>
          <form id="support" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                   <label for="file">Filename:</label>
                   <input type="file" name="logfile" id="file"><br/><br/>
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
           </form>
</div>
```

So then I try and upload the file:

```
$uploadDir = "/tmp/";


if(isset($_FILES['logfile']['name'])){

        $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['logfile']['name']);

        print "<p>{$_FILES['logfile']['name']}</p>\n";
        print "<p>{$uploadFile}</p>\n";

        # Delete if already exists
        if (file_exists($uploadFile)) {
                unlink($uploadFile);
        }

        // Recieve the file
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)) {
                displayMessage("Thanks");
        }
        else {
                # Couldnt move the file
                displayMessage("Error moving file");
        }
}
```

What happens is I get the message "Thanks" in my browser but no file. I've checked permissions, checked my nginx log - no errors at all. It looks like it is successful but nothing is being copied?

Edit:

Even this fails:

```
$myfile = fopen("/tmp/testfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$current = "John Smith\n";
fwrite($myfile, $current);
fclose($myfile);
```

Basically I cant write to /tmp for some reason, even though nginx is not reporting any error. I've also tried the same script under apache, with the same results.

```
drwxrwxrwt 18 root root 460 Aug 20 10:56 /tmp/
```

Comment: is /tmp/ folder present there at the same place where your php file ?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me. can you check the upload directory? where you have kept your tmp folder? just use if the same place of the file `$uploadDir="tmp/";`

```
<?php
$uploadDir = "";
if(isset($_FILES['logfile']['name'])){

    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['logfile']['name']);

    print "<p>{$_FILES['logfile']['name']}</p>\n";
    print "<p>{$uploadFile}</p>\n";

    # Delete if already exists
    if (file_exists($uploadFile)) {
       unlink($uploadFile);
    }
    // Recieve the file
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)) {
            echo "Thanks";
    }
    else {
            # Couldnt move the file
            echo "Error moving file";
    }
}
?>
<div>
 <p> Select a file </p>
      <form id="support" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
               <label for="file">Filename:</label>
               <input type="file" name="logfile" id="file"><br/><br/>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
       </form>
</div>
```